# getimagesize : failed to open stream: No such file or directory (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I get an error on the 4th line of this php statement and I am unsure why? The image is in one of my files inside my laravel project. The error occurs when I try and click on a button that is an image, for reference the image obviously doesn't load on the webpage, then I get this once clicking on it:

```
@php $customOgTag = false; @endphp



@if(View::hasSection('og-image'))

    @php

        $data = getimagesize(app()->view->getSections()['og-image-internal']);

        if($data[0] > 600){

            $customOgTag = true;

            $customOgTagWidth = $data[0];

            $customOgTagHeight = $data[1];

        }

    @endphp

@endif
```

The error reads:

> getimagesize(uploads/listings/1585288587880-2-800x467.jpg): failed to
> open stream: No such file or directory (View:
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/storzy-dev/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php)

Comment: `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan view:clear` then try again

Comment: @STA didn't do anything bro

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)